# Repeating notifications not repeating

Tags: android

I'd like to have a notification done weekly from the day it was set. It initializes when it gets called but not the second time.(I fast forwarded the phone clock to see if it would call it but it didn't). It must be the 7*calendar.getTimeInMillis(). How else would I go about having it set for weekly?

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnBootReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 7*calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

BroadCastReceiver class:

```
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CharSequence from = "from";
CharSequence message = "message";
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
Notification notif = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Comment: 7 * the current date will give you something rediculous like the year 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `7*calendar.getTimeInMillis()` is indeed the problem as `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` returns the time since 1970, so you basically set the repeating to **~42.5 * 7** years from now. You need to set the offset, e.g. **7 (days) * 24 (hours) * 60 (minutes) * 60 (seconds) * 1000 (millies)**.

After we cleared that - I suggest you avoid using the repeating, and instead set a new alarm each time the invoked code finishes its work, as there are some possible problems with the repeating mechanism.

Comment: I actually wanted to include that in this question. My next question is going to be on the BroadcastReceiver. I assume you're talking about that?

Comment: It is relevant for any AlarmManager usage I can think about, including broadcast receiver

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Ignore the setRepeating and just use set each time.

Comment: Yup, from my experience it is better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the current date * 7 you want:

> 7 days = 604 800 000 milliseconds

This is [how many milliseconds are in 7 days](http://tinyurl.com/82aamd5)

i.e.

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 604800000L, pendingIntent);
```